# I can't select Secondary Drawer Item in android

Tags: android, drawer

I am using [Material Drawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library. Here, I can select Primary Drawer Item but I can't select Second Drawer Item. What can be the problem?

```
home = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_home).withIcon(Entypo.Icon.ent_shopping_bag);
            settingProfile = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_settings_my_profile).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_account_box);
            setting = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_settings).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_settings);


            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    switch (position) {
                        case 1:
                            startActivity(new Intent(CargoPlaceActivity.this, FirstActivity.class));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            startActivity(new Intent(CargoPlaceActivity.this, UpdateProfile.class));
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            startActivity(new Intent(CargoPlaceActivity.this, Setting.class));
                            break;
                        default:
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            })
.build();
```

Comment: can you give me the exact file url ?